# How can I get a container running again, that has stopped now but was running before

Tags: nginx, docker, containers

I had this container running:

```
docker run -d -P -v $HOME/site:/usr/share/nginx/html --name mysite nginx
```

and then I stopped it

These are my images:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
nginx               1.9.2               319d2015d149        6 days ago          132.8 MB
nginx               latest              319d2015d149        6 days ago          132.8 MB
nginx               1                   319d2015d149        6 days ago          132.8 MB
nginx               1.9                 319d2015d149        6 days ago          132.8 MB
```

no containers running:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS  PORTS               NAMES
```

the container was running but it has stopped an hour ago:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
c1845f606c3e        nginx:1             "nginx -g 'daemon of   About an hour ago   Exited (0) About an hour ago                       mysite
```

** How can I get a container running again, that has stopped now but was running before **

NOTE: Working on this [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/)

Comment: think the answer is: `docker start mysite` from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/2es5jw/docker-cheat-sheet-with-examples)

Comment: you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

think the answer is: `docker start mysite` from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/2es5jw/docker-cheat-sheet-with-examples)